# Convert SQL subquery in Linq

Tags: sql, linq

how do i convert my subquery in linq ? my query is  :

```
select *
from Product 
where ID in 
(
   select distinct(sku.ProductId) 
   from SiteProducts sp
   inner join ProductSKU sku on sp.ProductId = sku.Id
   where sp.siteid = 2
)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
from p in db.Product
where (from sp in db.SiteProducts
       join sku in db.ProductSKU on sp.ProductId equals sku.Id
       where sp.siteid == 2
       select sku.ProductId).Distinct().Contains(p.ID)
select p
```